# Jquery datepicker value on Controller action method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3

I've created a extension method of Jquery datepicker, below are the source code.

```
public static string DatePicker(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, DateTime? value)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        return "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"
               + "$(function() {"
               + "$(\"#" + name +
               "\").datepicker({changeMonth: true,changeYear: true, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', duration: 0});"
               + "});"
               + "</script>"
               + "<input type=\"text\" size=\"10\" value=\""
               + FormattedDate(value)
               + "\" id=\""
               + name.Replace('.', '_')
               + "\" name=\""
               + name + "\"/>";
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

I have used the above extension method in the View.

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Committee.AppointedDate)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.Raw(Html.DatePicker("CommitteeAppointedDate", Model.Committee.AppointedDate))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Committee.AppointedDate)
</div>
```

When I click on submit button, the view model which is holding above appointed date is showing `DateTime.MinValue` at the controller action method.

Please let us know what's wrong with the above code.

Comment: anyway, use `StringBuilder`, not string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: because your input name should be `"Committee.AppointedDate"` but you pass `"CommitteeAppointedDate"`.